eigenvalues of contraction
Assume $A - B$ is a contraction, i.e., its spectral radius is smaller than $1$. We also assume $A$ is diagonalizable.
I am trying to show that if $x^TB=0$, then $x^T$ can be written as a sum of eigenvectors of $A$ such that these eigenvectors have eigenvalues with magnitude smaller than $1$. If this is not true, are there assumptions I can add so that it holds?

Are those symmetric matrices? because otherwise a contraction means something different than all eigenvalues less than 1

These are not necessarily symmetric matrices.

Take
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 0& 5/4
\end{pmatrix}
-
\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1/2 \\ 0& 1/2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2\\ 0& 3/4
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This is a contraction since its norm is strictly less than 1. The only vector in the left kernel of $B$ is the all-ones vector, that cannot be written as a multiple of the only eigenvector of $A$ relative to the eigenvalue 0 that is $(1 \,\,0)$.
